# SQL UPDATE using BASH loop

Tags: sql, oracle, bash

We changed some usernames in our application however there are some history etc. in the database that also needs to be updated. There is a file `update_users.list` that has the old username and new username separated by space, 2 user names per line.

Would the below script be correct, or are there some noticeable issues with it?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat update_users.list | while read old_user new_user
do
sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db > user_output.log <<EOF
UPDATE auf_kopf SET kopf_sach = '%${new_user}%' WHERE kopf_sach = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE auf_prot SET sach_bearb = '%${new_user}%' WHERE sach_bearb = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE auf_prot_hint SET sach_bearb = '%${new_user}%' WHERE sach_bearb = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE ordhist SET user_code = '%${new_user}%' WHERE user_code = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE liefer_daten SET sach_bearb = '%${new_user}%' WHERE sach_bearb = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE shipment_head SET shipment_sach = '%${new_user}%' WHERE shipment_sach = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE lager_bew SET lb_sachbearb = '%${new_user}%' WHERE lb_sachbearb = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE lager_abzu SET abzu_sachbearb = '%${new_user}%' WHERE abzu_sachbearb = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE best_kopf SET best_sach = '%${new_user}%' WHERE best_sach = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE rcpt_header SET user_name = '%${new_user}%' WHERE user_name = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE stat_kopf SET st_kopf_sach = '%${new_user}%' WHERE st_kopf_sach = '%${old_user}%';
UPDATE stat_mod SET stat_user = '%${new_user}%' WHERE stat_user = '%${old_user}%';
/
exit
EOF
```

Comment: You can add an `echo` in the beginning of each line. This way you will see the output without having it executed. Once you are sure it has no parsing problems, go and execute it.

Comment: Can you post an example? I receive `SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "UPDA..." - rest of line ignored.`.

Comment: You're missing 'done' too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write the input to SQL-scriptfile first and then execute it:

```
awk '{print "UPDATE TABLE usertable SET col=" $2 " WHERE col=" $1 ";"}' <input >script.sql; 
echo "/" >>script.sql;  
sqlplus user/pass @script.sql;
```